# Implement sort of "static abstract and inheritable" method

Tags: java, android, inheritance, static, abstract

I am working on an Android App, I got this situation:

-GenericOrderDetailFragment, an Abstract Class that extends Fragment.

-Three non-abstract "sons" of this class: LinesFragment, HeaderFragment, NoteFragment.

There are plenty of methods that are the same in the three sons, so i declare then on the abstract class, that is why it exists.

I'm stuck with one in particular. By now, I put this method inside the son and it works great:

```
public class LinesFragment extends GenericOrderDetailFragment {

    [...]

    public static LinesFragment newInstance(Order o) {
        LinesFragment fragment = new LinesFragment();
        putSerializable(o, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    [...]

}
```

This method is identical in all the sons, except for the return type: LinesFragment should return a LinesFragment instance, HeaderFragment should return a HeaderFragment istance ... I wanna put this as a mustoverride in the father class, but I cannot do this because of:

Simply put the

```
public static GenericOrderDetailFragment newInstance(Order o) {
    GenericOrderDetailFragment fragment = new GenericOrderDetailFragment();
    putSerializable(o, fragment);
    return fragment;
}
```

method does not work, simply because I cannot istantiate a GenericOrderDetailFragment (It is abstract). I cannot istantiate a ***this***.getClass() item, 'cause there is not ***this***: the method is static!

I cannot declare a "static abstract" method (in java static is "not overridable" and abstract is "mustoverride", so they cannot live together), so I cannot force the user who extends GenericOrderDetailFragment to override the method.

There are methods I MUSToverride if I extend this Generic Class, so I cannot declare not-abstract the father class.

Is ther any workaround I can use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
public static <T extends GenericOrderDetailFragment> T newInstance(Class<T> cl, Order o) {
    Constructor<T> c = cl.getConstructor();
    T fragment = c.newInstance();
    ...
}
```

Please note that I left out any `Exception`. So you have to do the exception handling yourself.

But basically this should be what you are searching for.

Comment: Wow, this works nearly perfect, thanks a lot! Only one little little note: I have to _pass_ the class to make it work [ OrderDetailNotesFragment.newInstance(_OrderDetailNotesFragment.class_,toSaveOrder); ]. Is there a more compact way to write it? newIstance is static, so i cannot simply pass in an automatic way _this_ class, cause there is not any _this_! Thanks a LOT anyway!

Comment: @SimoneChelo No there is no way I know to omit the class in the method call. Also ou have to tell the method which class to create...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your user to override `newInstance(Order o)`, you could throw an `Exception` in the `newInstance(Order o)` of the `GenericOrderDetailFragment`. This way, you force your user to override it.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, I'll use this in case I wanna _mustoverride_ a _static_ method! Thanks!